# OCaml Functors Sort

Tags: ocaml

I am a beginner in OCaml and I'm trying to understand functors, I'm developing a "general sort function" with functors that can takes array, list, string and return an ordered list, array, string.
Can someone help me with this?
I've done this

```
module type Comparable= sig 
  type t 
  val compare : t -> t -> int
  val fold_left : ('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a
end;;

module Make_sort(S: Comparable)= struct
  type  t= S.t
  type et= S.t list
  
  let order t= function
    |[] -> 0
    |a::b -> S.fold_left (S.compare (a t)(b t)) ;;
  
end;;
```

Comment: What specifically is the problem?

Comment: this one is the error on the last 'b' :Error: This expression has type ('a -> S.t) list
This is not a function; it cannot be applied. However i don't know if this code really do a sort for every different type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think that your intuition is correct but there is small confusion between the value level and the type level, ie: `S.compare (a t)(b t)` this expression is not valid (`a` and `b`) must be `functions`, this why I think that you try to give the sense of `'a t`.
But, I understand what you try to do, so here is a small primer on functor (function from module to module), using a small subset of your example.

#### First, in order to sort we need to define how to order

Exactly as you did, we can start with a signature (`COMPARABLE`) which handle the "notion of comparison". For example:

```ml
module type COMPARABLE = sig

  (** something which is comparable. *)
  type t

  (** [compare x y] returns 1 if x > y, 0 if x = 0 and -1 if x < 0 *)
  val compare : t -> t -> int
    
end
```

With this signature, it is easy to define module which are comparable, for example, for `Int`:

```ml
module Int_comparable : 
    COMPARABLE with type t = int = 
struct 

  type t = int
  let compare x y = 
    if x > y then 1 
    else if x = 0 then 0
    else -1
end
```

> Note that module are **candidate for a signature only if the module match the signature** so de anotation `: COMPARABLE with type t = int` is not very necessary. And, since `Int` (the module from the stdlib) already implement `compare` and a type `t`, it is not necessary to define it. You can just pass `Int` when you need a comparable.

#### Now, we can define somethign "sortable"

In this very small example, something which is comparable seems to be sortable. In other words, **if I have a COMPARABLE, I can sort**. This relation (If I have X, I can have Y) seems quite suitable for using a **functor** (so, I give you a COMPARABLE and you give me something sortable). Here is a proposition:

```ml
module Sortable (C : COMPARABLE) : sig

  (** if something is comparable, it is sortable. *)
  type t = C.t

  (** [max_of x y] returns the greater between x and y. *)
  val max_of : t -> t -> t

  (** [min_of x y] returns the lower between x and y. *)
  val min_of : t -> t -> t

  (** [sort x y] returns an ordered tuple [(max_of x y, min_of x y)]. *)
  val sort : t -> t -> (t * t)
    
end = struct
  
  type t = C.t
             
  let max_of x y =
    let value = C.compare x y in
    if value > 0 then x
    else y
      
  let min_of x y =
    let value = C.compare x y in
    if value < 0 then x
    else y

  let sort x y =
    if (C.compare x y) >= 0 then (y, x) else (x, y) 
end
```

It is probably possible to add more helpers in the module, but I'll keep the implementation as simple as possible. So now, if I want have sortable capabilities for `Int.t` I can just use the module `Int` (from stdlib: https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Int.html) which has a `type t` and `compare` like this

```ml
module Sortable_int = Sortable (Int)
```

Now, you have the basis. For traversing using Sort, you can implement a signature (`Foldable` for example) and I think you have all the bricks in your hands to generalize the logic of sorting collections (modulo a little algorithmic!)